# dynamic speech recognition in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have a simple app, where a user asks, can a yorkie eat...
the answer is either yes its safe for a yorkie to it this or the answer is, No, its not save for a yorkie to eat that

and i have here this script(its a bit messy)

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()

def canEat():
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say('A Yorkie can eat bananas')  
    engine.runAndWait() 


def canNoteat():
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say('A Yorkie can NOT eat grapes')  
    engine.runAndWait()

def eatInModeration():
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say('A Yorkie can NOT eat grapes')  
    engine.runAndWait()



try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
        if 'bananas'  in command:
            print('A Yorkie can eat bananas')
            canEat()
            #SpeakText()
        elif 'watermelon' in command:
            print(' A yorkie can eat watermelons')
        elif 'coconut'  in command:
            print(' A yorkie can eat coconuts')
        elif 'avocados' in command:
            print('No, a Yorkie can not eat avocados')
        elif 'grapes' in command:
            print('Yorkies cant eat grapes or raisins')
            canNoteat()


except:
    pass
```

What I try to achieve is.
I dont want as answer only: yes he can eat this or that, or no he cant eat this or that.
If a user asks, can a yorkie eat bananas:
the answer should be
Yes a yorkie can eat bananas:
If a useer asks, can a yorkie eat grapes.
the answer should be
No, a yorkie cant eat grapes:

So basically i want to use the fruit in the answer but i dont want to hardcode it every time.
So is ther a way where i can listen for the fruit and than say it?

I know i could do it like this

```
if 'grapes' in command:
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say('A Yorkie can Not eat grapes')  
    engine.runAndWait()
```

I have a list of hundreds of fruits and i dont want to repeat myself over and over again.
I want to make the code more dynamic

so i have a list with fruits he can eat and a list with fruits he cant eat
if the fruit is in the list of what he can eat.
I want to say the name out loud

I know this might be a confusing question but it should be simple i just cant figure out how to do it

Updated

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()


fruits_can_eat = ['bananas', 'beef', 'pork', 'corn', 'fish', 'strawberries']
fruits_can_not_eat = ['grapes', 'avocado', 'chocolate']



def canEat():
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say(word)  
    engine.runAndWait() 

def canNotEat():
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say(word)  
    engine.runAndWait()


try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
        for word in command:
            if word in fruits_can_eat:
                canEat(word)
            elif word in fruits_can_not_eat:
                canNotEat(word)


except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
for word in command:
    if word in can_eat_fruit_list:
        canEat(word)
    else if word in can_not_eat_fruit_list:
        canNotEat(word)
```

And then alter canEat() and canNotEat() to use word instead of hardcoded.

Comment: thats smart, i will try this

Comment: Wonderful!  The only thing this might run into is if they ask about multiple you want to make sure it handles that correctly.  Let me know if it works for ya!

Comment: i updated the question- the new code is below updated. I dont understand where i get "word" from